# Dealing with overlapping text in OCR: Identifying different color text in images using Python and OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, overlap

## Recognize different color text in overlapping in Python.

I have a text recognition problem about different color text overlaping. Like Below:
[Origin image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBU00.png)
And I use my own OCR model to recognize the date in the image but it alwayse false because of the chinese text below it. Therefore, I want to clean the chinese text so that my OCR model could recognize it.
And I have try to transfer my image from RGB to CMYK. To just get black color text like below:
[CMYK_test image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBfNw.jpg)

```
image = cv2.imread('./test_image/test3.png')
imgFloat = image.astype(np.float) / 255.
kChannel = 1 - np.max(imgFloat, axis=2)
kChannel = (255 * kChannel).astype(np.uint8)

binaryThresh = 135
_, binaryImage = cv2.threshold(kChannel, binaryThresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Use a little bit of morphology to clean the mask:
# Set kernel (structuring element) size:
kernelSize = 3
# Set morph operation iterations:
opIterations = 1
# Get the structuring element:
morphKernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (kernelSize, kernelSize))
# Perform closing:
invert = cv2.morphologyEx(binaryImage, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, morphKernel, None, None, opIterations, cv2.BORDER_REFLECT101)

cv2.imshow("result",invert)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cv2.imwrite("./test_image/CMYK_test.jpg",invert)
```

Moreover, I have try to transfer my image from RGB to HSV. To just get black color text like below:
[HSV_test image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myIBT.jpg)

```
image = cv2.imread('./test_image/test3.png')

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) 
h,s,v = cv2.split(hsv)

mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, (0,0,0), (180, 50, 150))
dst1 = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)
dst1 = cv2.cvtColor(dst1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

cv2.imshow("result",dst1)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cv2.imwrite("./test_image/hsv_test.jpg",dst1)
```

But this two result are not good enough. Please help me to deal with it or give me some suggestions. Thank you very much.